# How does Flash Player load the main SWF file?

Tags: actionscript, load, flash, lazy-loading

**UPDATE:**

It seems that everyone didn't read my question thoroughly, all answers suggest me preloading or using external assets. So anyone willing to answer, please take notice to **bold questions** in this post. Thanks!

---

I'm developing a simple Flash application which has only one SWF file. I want the SWF movie to start playing asap so I don't build a preloader for it. What happen if my actionscript code refers to resources which haven't been loaded yet?

For example, the code cause the playhead to jump from frame `1` to frame `20` when the movie has just been loaded up to frame `10`. **In that case, flash player will?**

- Block the script execution, stop playing, continue loading from frame `11` to `20` (without executing script), jump to frame `20` and invoke script at that frame when it's loaded?
- Block the script execution, stop playing, ignore loading frame `11` to `19`, load frame `20`, jump to frame `20` and invoke script at that frame?
- Ignore jumping to frame `20`, continue executing next statements after the go to frame `20` statement?
- Or anything else?

**If flash player doesn't ignore jumping to frame `20`, any `event` is triggered when frame `20` is loaded completely?**

**Note:** Answers for the first question should focus on my example, cover all circumstances (such as attach movie from library...) is better, but not necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to fine tune your loading experience, dont rely on Flash's automatic loading mechanisms. And dont use frames. Use something like [Bulkloader](http://code.google.com/p/bulk-loader/) to load your assets. Your .swf file should only contain assets, that are needed to be displayed on the first frame, and all the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some test using Adobe Flash Professional in order to find the answer for my question. Everyone who's interested can reproduce the test by doing the following steps in Adobe Flash:

1. Create a movie with some frame, each frame contains one image and some actionscript code, for example.
2. Select menu *Control -> Test Movie -> in Flash Professional*: The debug player will be displayed
3. In the debug player, select menu *View -> Download Settings* then choose your desired download speed
4. Also in the debug player, make sure *Bandwidth Profiler* and *Simulate Download* under *View* menu are checked.

If the script doesn't change the playhead, Flash player will:

1. Load frame 1 and wait until it's loaded completely
2. Go to frame 1
3. Execute script on frame 1
4. Display frame 1
5. Doing above steps for frame 2, and so on... (Stay at frame 1 until frame 2 is loaded completely, then go to frame 2, execute script, display...)

If the script change the playhead, e.g. jump from frame 1 to frame 20, Flash player will:

1. Continue to execute all script statements in frame 1 (even though these statements follow the jumping statement) and display frame 1.
2. If frame 20 is loaded, jump to frame 20, execute script on it & display it. If it isn't loaded, jump to nearest loaded frame (in my example in the question is frame 10) but do not execute script on that frame.

Answer (score 3):

Flash will always load all the frames before running the application. However, the **frame contents** might not be fully loaded. So if you have some images on frame 20, they might not appear.

But basically you shouldn't rely on Flash to load things for you - it might do it in the order you want, but maybe it won't. If you have many assets and you are jumping from frame to frame, you should handle the loading yourself using the `Loader` class.

Comment: For some reason I don't want to fully load the movie before playing it or load external resource when needed.

Comment: @ExpExc, it's a bit of a contradiction. You don't want to load everything, and you don't want to load things as needed either. So how do you want to handle loading assets?

Comment: I want to load things already embedded into the main swf when needed, don't want to load from external. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't remember having seen anything about this in the doc. My guess is that whether an asset is going to be loaded or not when you get to the frame is undefined. It probably depends on how was compiled the SWF, in which order the assets were added, the internet connection speed, etc. The only way to get things to load as you want is to load them by code.

Comment: @ExpExc, I believe that is the default method of loading, i.e. When something needs to be displayed, the load is started (of course, this is only if the asset is not embedded)

Comment: @Laurent, what did you mean _"Flash will always load all the frames before running the application"_?

Comment: "Flash will always load all the frames before running the application." === untrue. It will not.

Answer (score 1):

Flash player will try to jump to frame 20. But it will only go as far as the frames that are loaded. So if you tell it to go to 20, and only 10 are loaded, you will go to 10.

Calling resources in code not yest loaded will either throw an error, or define that object as null. Needless to say, this needs to be avoided. Load those resources first.

A good solution is to use the -frame compiler argument to create a 2-frame flash movie. the first contains your preloader, and the second frame contains the complete app. that way you can preload what you need before the full functionality is called for.

Here is an example fo how to do that.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Zachary Foley
     */
    public class Preloader extends MovieClip 
    {

        public function Preloader() 
        {
            if (stage) {
                stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
                stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            }
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkFrame);
            loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progress);
            loaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioError);

            // TODO show loader
        }

        private function ioError(e:IOErrorEvent):void 
        {
            trace(e.text);
        }

        private function progress(e:ProgressEvent):void 
        {
            // TODO update loader
        }

        private function checkFrame(e:Event):void 
        {
            if (currentFrame == totalFrames) 
            {
                stop();
                loadingFinished();
            }
        }

        private function loadingFinished():void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkFrame);
            loaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progress);
            loaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioError);

            // TODO hide loader

            startup();
        }

        private function startup():void 
        {
            var mainClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("Main") as Class;
            addChild(new mainClass() as DisplayObject);
        }

    }

}
```

To use this you need to add the frame argument to your build. For this example the frame argument would be:

```
-frame start Main
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't want to use a preloader. Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: You are welcome. But consider the word "preloader" to be equivalent to "the part of the swf that can play without preloaded assets" - it doesn't have to be a boring old percent counter. If you don't want errors, you will need something that effectively performs the function of a preloader, whether it looks like a traditional preloader or not.

Comment: I definitely understand the fact that resources must be available before the code can refer to them. I just don't want to load frame by frame consecutively but afaIk, Flash doesn't allow to load desired frame on demand. _Preloader_ in my previous comment means loading completely before playing as your code do. It may frustrate users, so my solution now is to poll and wait for a frame loaded before going to that frame.

Comment: I've made some test, the result as you pointed out: _Flash player will try to jump to frame 20. But it will only go as far as the frames that are loaded_. +1 for your answer. (Read my answer for detail)

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have to define the progressive loading method for your project.

First of all develop external assets, initially load only one and display it. Just start second one loading and manage display with your loaded UI only. So you can avoid the preloader. When you will get loaded item list just perform one by one displaying in progressive manner.

first display only one.
After second loading first & second one..
then so on you have to manage

Other wise you have to wait on first display upto next display assets loading will be over. And don't show pre-loader this time.

Answer (score 0):

in AS2, try this code. Loading progress show at first frame, and main content show at 3rd frame. 
This code is in ActionScript 2.0 reference(getBytesLoaded). http://help.adobe.com/ko_KR/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/00001304.html#1333866

```
if (this._framesloaded<this._totalframes) {
    this.gotoAndPlay(1);
} else {
    this.gotoAndStop(3);
}
```

in AS3, use This.

```
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
```